# Return Join Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to return a join to my class and It is giving me the following error.

**Error 1 Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List' C:\Projetos_ASP.NET\AdvanceTechniques\Models\Repository\ProductRepository.cs 40 30 AdvanceTechniques**

Follows the code below.

```
public List<Line> Get()
{
    return context.
        Lines.
        Join(
            context.Products,
            lines => lines.ID,
            products => products.LineID,
            ((products, lines)
                => new { lines, products}
        )).
        OrderByDescending(products => products.products.ID).ToList();
}
```

Follow my Entity

```
public partial class Line
    {
        public Line()
        {
            this.Products = new List<Product>();
        }
        [Required]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DesktopImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string MobileImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AltImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Position { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a `Join` to return products for each line, you only have to Include Products and then return them like:

```
return context.Lines.Include("Products").ToList();
```